# Changing minDate and maxDate on the fly using jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm having a particular issue with the jQuery Datepicker. I can easily add a date range, but I want the selectable range to change depending on the event the user has picked.

So if they pick event #1, they can only pick dates from event #1's date range.

I've written a simple little function that gets called whenever the user selects a new event, but it only ever shows the initially set minDate/maxDate values.

```
function datepicker(startDate, endDate) {
  $( "#date" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date(startDate),
    maxDate: new Date(endDate),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
  });
}
```

I've tried calling `$('#date').datepicker('remove');` before calling the above function again, to see if it creates a new instance with the correct dates, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've checked all the data through developer tools and everything is being called and passed correctly. Is there anything I can do to make this work how I want it to?

Comment: DId you try `$('#date').datepicker('option', {minDate: new Date(startDate)});` per http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option  That allows you to change the options on the fly.

Comment: @StevenVondruska I didn't see that. Thank you, it worked a treat! Put it in an answer if you like.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have a couple of options...

1) You need to call the `destroy()` method not `remove()` so...

```
$('#date').datepicker('destroy');
```

Then call your method to recreate the `datepicker` object.

2) You can update the property of the existing `object` via

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(startDate));
$('#date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(endDate));
```

or...

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', { minDate: new Date(startDate),
                                  maxDate: new Date(endDate) });
```

Comment: The new API calls for "minDate" or "maxDate" rather than "minValue" or "maxValue".  Took me 10 minutes to realize this (face palm).

Comment: I tried this code but I am getting error that Uncaught Type Error: datepicker is not a function. =S

Comment: @MahrukhMehmood this means that you don't have the correct files included on the page. Make sure you have jQuery UI included.

Comment: Yes I cleaned my cache, cookies ect all content and updated my js files and finally able to achieve this. Whew :)

Answer (score 10):

For from / to date, here is how I implemented restricting the dates based on the date entered in the other datepicker. Works pretty good:

```
function activateDatePickers() {
    $("#aDateFrom").datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            $("#aDateTo").datepicker(
                    "change",
                    { minDate: new Date($('#aDateFrom').val()) }
            );
        }
    });
    $("#aDateTo").datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            $("#aDateFrom").datepicker(
                    "change",
                    { maxDate: new Date($('#aDateTo').val()) }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#aDateFrom").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        //- get date from another datepicker without language dependencies
        var minDate = $('#aDateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
        $("#aDateTo").datepicker("change", { minDate: minDate });
    }
});

$("#aDateTo").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        //- get date from another datepicker without language dependencies
        var maxDate = $('#aDateTo').datepicker('getDate');
        $("#aDateFrom").datepicker("change", { maxDate: maxDate });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed min date property of date time picker by using this

```
$('#date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(startDate);
```

I hope this one help to someone !

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using Datepicker, but for some people who are just using HTML5 input date like me, there is an example how you can do the same:
[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/seguelador/08ew4pme/)

```
$('#start_date').change(function(){
  var start_date = $(this).val();
  $('#end_date').prop({
    min: start_date
  });
});


/*  prop() method works since jquery 1.6, if you are using a previus version, you can use attr() method.*/
```