# jQuery Datepicker minDate not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers 'startDate' and 'targetDate'.I want to set the minDate of the 'targetDate' as the value of 'startDate'.The following 
code is not working.ie,the minDate of 'targetDate' is not set.

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                dateFormat : "dd-M-yy",
                minDate : 0,

                showMonthAfterYear : true,
                onClose : function() {

                    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
                }
            });
            $("#targetDate").datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                dateFormat : "dd-M-yy",
                minDate : new Date($("#startDate").val()),
                showMonthAfterYear : true,
                onClose : function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
                }

            });
```

Comment: Where you are calling the function for targetDate ?

Comment: calling from this text box. <form:input path="targetDate" id="targetDate" />

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly - you need to change the `minDate` of the targetDate datepicker during the `onClose` event of the startDate datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set min-date of *targetDate* in [**onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of *startDate*

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Use

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $('#targetDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
      }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/fmuerho1/1/)