# Change jQuery UI datepicker minDate dynamically

Tags: jquery, datepicker, mindate

I need to change `minDate` of jQuery's [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) each the time value of `#position` or `#type` changes. Currently the value for the `minDate` changes only the first time either `#position` or `#type` evokes the `.change()` method.

I am currently using the code below:

```
$("#position, #type").change(function(){
     var pos = $("#position").val();
     var type = $("#type").val();
     var url =  "getdate/"+type+"/"+pos;
     $.get(url, function(msg){
         $('.date1').datepicker({
             MinDate: msg
         });
     });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are re-initiating the `.datepicker` method everytime there is a `.change()` event.

Instead of this, initiate the `datepicker` once on the class `.date1` and then change `MinDate` as follows:

```
$('.date1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', msg);
```

So this would yield:

```
// first initialise
$('.date1').datepicker({
     MinDate: msg
});

$("#position, #type").change(function(){
     var pos = $("#position").val();
     var type = $("#type").val();
     var url =  "getdate/"+type+"/"+pos;
     $.get(url, function(msg){
        // then change
        $('.date1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', msg);
     });
})
```

---

Alternatively, you can also destroy the `.datepicker` object as follows:

```
$('.date1').datepicker('destroy');
```

And then recreate the object as in your own code. So combined this would yield:

```
// first initialise
$('.date1').datepicker({
     MinDate: msg
});

$("#position, #type").change(function(){
     var pos = $("#position").val();
     var type = $("#type").val();
     var url =  "getdate/"+type+"/"+pos;
     $.get(url, function(msg){
        // first destroy
        $('.date1').datepicker('destroy');
        // then recreate
        $('.date1').datepicker({
           MinDate: msg
        });
     });
})
```

Also, please consult this question and answer:

[jQuery DatePicker -- Changing minDate and maxDate on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly/16267968#16267968)