# DatePicker in jquery is not loaded for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a `datepicker` in my page and also I have two radio buttons as follows.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio1" checked> Radio 1 

<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio2" >Radio 2
```

**My datepicker html is:**

```
<input 
       type="text" 
       id="mydatepicker" 
       aria-controls="sample_1" 
       class="form-control input-small input-inline" >
```

**My JS code is:**

```
$('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: EnableDisableDates
});

function EnableDisableDates(date) {
    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
    if ($("#radio1").is(':checked') == false) {
        if (date < Date.parse('11/23/2015'))
            return {enabled: false};
    }
    else {
         return [true];
    }
}
```

I want to show all the dates on selecting **Radio 1** and I want to **disable dates** on selecting radio button 2 **(Radio 2)** ***before 23-Nov-2015()***.

The above is my scenario.

**My problem is:**

For first time it loads, it is working fine for the **Radio 1** i.e. it enables all the dates for **Radio 1**.

On selecting the **Radio 2**, it is not calling the method EnableDisableDates method of **`beforeShowDay`** property in datepicker.

I don't know why it is not calling the method. Help me to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ca use minDate to disable dates instead of looing it manually which will cost perfomance:

Try this:

**JS**

```
$(function() {   
   $(".radio1").change(function () {    
    if($(".radio1:checked").val()=="radio2"){
      $('#mydatepicker').datepicker('destroy');
        $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',        
          minDate: '11/23/2015'
        });
    }else{
      $('#mydatepicker').datepicker('destroy');
      $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                  
        });      
   }
  });
 $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}); 
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="radio" class="radio1" name="radio1" value="radio1" checked> Radio 1 
 <input type="radio" class="radio1" name="radio1" value="radio2" >Radio 2<input 
         type="text" 
         id="mydatepicker" 
         aria-controls="sample_1" 
         class="form-control input-small input-inline" >
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/703/)

update:

we have used the destroy to create new instance of datepicker
[jQuery DatePicker -- Changing minDate and maxDate on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly) see this

Comment: Once, if I destroy the datepicker, it is showing all the dates. Nothing has been initialized after destroying the datepicker.

Comment: did you checked my fiddle and did you clicked radio

Comment: This is what it is doing right "I want to show all the dates on selecting Radio 1 and I want to disable dates on selecting radio button 2 (Radio 2) before 23-Nov-2015()." as per your requirement

Comment: Are you getting that?. I'm not getting here. I can able to select all the dates except 7th December which is disabled.

Comment: I'm using chrome version:34.0.1847.3. Is there any problem with that

Comment: Yes Vikash , I am getting expected result, or you can even see the conditions in code and try to write by your own code.

Comment: Hey bro seriously, here it is not working. I don't know why?

Comment: ok np , debug it in console you might get it , Please accept and upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. In my case it was a dropdown and based on the dropdown it I was disabling certain days in the datepicker. It was working for the change I made. But for second change it was not working.

Finally the solution I got was datepicker('remove').

So this should work with just adding one line of code in the change function.

```
$('#mydatepicker').datepicker('remove');
```

So your code should like this:

```
$(".radio1").change(function () {
$('#mydatepicker').datepicker('remove');
if($(".radio1:checked").val()=="radio2"){
  $('#mydatepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',        
      minDate: '11/23/2015'
    });
}else{
  $('#mydatepicker').datepicker('destroy');
  $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                  
    });
```

}
  });