# maxdate not working in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my datepicker, the `maxDate` option is not working

The code is,

```
 $('#start_date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', 
    autoclose: true, 
    clearBtn: true, 
    maxDate: new Date()
    }).on('change', function (ev) {

    $('#end_date').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', setDate: $('#start_date').val(), autoclose: true, clearBtn: true, maxDate: new Date()});
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DatePicker -- Changing minDate and maxDate on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly)

Comment: why are you calling `#enddate` two times? You can set the same attribute in one function.

Comment: ok, I changed that

Comment: So you want to set date with `enddate` with `startdate` selected date, and also want to set maxDate with current date. Am I right ?

Comment: yes, I want to set end_date with selected start_date and also disable future dates from these two calendars (start_date and end_date)

Comment: @Arya, Have you checked my answer? If it still not working for your usecase, do comment for the answer. I will try to help you for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your maxDate Not current date:
e.g. if you want to selection between some criterial date

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: "+1m +1w"
});
```

Comment: $('#end_date').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', startDate: $('#start_date').val(), autoclose: true, clearBtn: true, maxDate: new Date()});
Here you have used startDate what it means?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all what you want like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function () {
            var dt2 = $('#enddate');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //add 30 days to selected date
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //minDate of enddate datepicker = startdate selected day
            dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            //sets enddate maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
            //first day which can be selected in enddate is selected date in startdate
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            //same for startdate
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
    $('#enddate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to disable future dates from calendar.

Comment: This is for reference. You need to change little bit.

Comment: Did you use the same code ? What error you are getting ?