# jQuery Datepicker limit end date to one week without passing previous day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am looking to have start day default to yesterday and the end date to default to yesterday as well to begin with. This is the max date at all times.

I am then looking to make it allow the end date to have a max of 7 days after the start date once the user changes the start date. How would I do this?

The code:

```
var StrtDate = $('#strtDate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: -1,
    maxDate: -1,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        createEndDates.not(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
    }
});
$('#strtDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');

var EdDates = $('#edDate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: -1,
    maxDate: -1,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    }
});
$('#edDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

Please let me know how you would solve this.
Thanks a ton.

Comment: Once a new start date is selected you need to destroy end date datepicker and create a new one for new interval. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code**

you can set `maxDate` of `$('#edDate')` on selecting `$('#strtDate')`

```js
var endDate;
var StrtDate = $('#strtDate').datepicker({
defaultDate: -1,
maxDate: -1,
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
 endDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
 var final=new Date(endDate);
 final.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7);
 $('#edDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate',final);
}
});
$('#strtDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
var EdDates = $('#edDate').datepicker({
defaultDate: -1,
maxDate: -1,
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
}
});
$('#edDate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
start date: <input type="text" id="strtDate" name="date1"/> <br/>
end date: <input type="text" id="edDate" name="date2"/>
```

Comment: I thought I did this before. It works for me now. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help you bro :)Happy Coding::)

Comment: I also added some lines on keeping the limit to a maximum of yesterday. I stored the original date as a global variable then I make sure it's not passing that day by calculating the date difference.