# Set limit to next 365 days in datetimepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I want my datetimepicker dialog box to set limit to next 365 days(1 year). How can I get this using Jquery. here is my code.

```
$('.dt-expiry-date-time').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: new Date(),
    step: 5,
    minDate: new Date(),
});
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: var now = new Date; maxDate: new Date(now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear())) add this prop to default of datetimepicker

Comment: Well, try use Google, or take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly

Comment: try this in the datepicker  yearRange: "0 : +1"

Comment: check this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxDate: 365` in your jquery date picker configuration. This will automatically sets the maximum date to 365 days from current date.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: 365
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        maxDate: 365
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Comment: unable to do in datetimepicker it disables the dates when I'm trying your suggestion.

Comment: @DhavalMistry Yes, that will disable the dates after 1 year. So, what do you want after the 365 days?

Comment: nope sir I want exactly what you have given me in suggestion but when I trying this is my code it disabling all dates. I'm using datetimepicker.

Comment: It will not disable all dates. It will disable the date after 1 year. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: but in my case, It's disabling all dates, sir.

Comment: @DhavalMistry can u put your code in a fiddle?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue.. here is the code.

```
 $('.dt-expiry-date-time').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: new Date(),
    step: 5,
    minDate: '-1970/01/01',
    maxDate: '+1970/12/31'
});
```