# Set custom minDate for Datepicker jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to set up a custom minDate for my datepicker.
I getting a custom date value from my input:

```
var currentScheduledDate = jQuery("#scheduled_at").val();
```

And I want to set my datepicker to start from the custom date + 3 days

These are my params:

```
            {
                closeText: "Schließen",
                prevText: "&#x3C;Zurück",
                nextText: "Vor&#x3E;",
                currentText: "Heute",
                monthNames: [ "Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni",
                    "Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember" ],
                monthNamesShort: [ "Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai","Jun",
                    "Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez" ],
                dayNames: [ "Sonntag","Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag" ],
                dayNamesShort: [ "So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa" ],
                dayNamesMin: [ "So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa" ],
                weekHeader: "KW",
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: "",
                minDate: currentScheduledDate.getDate()+3,
                maxDate: "+3M" ,
                dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
                beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends,
                firstDay: 1
            }
```

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
minDate: currentScheduledDate.getDate()+3,
```

Any idea how to set this ? Thank you

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, is there any error ? Can we have your value ?

Comment: Check this if useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly

Comment: @Baptiste I'm getting this error: `currentScheduledDate.getDate is not a function`