# jQuery datepicker - increasing mindDate by one day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers. The minDate in the 2cnd can only be the same or heigher then the 1st one. I would like to modify this code to increase the minDate by one day, but I somehow brokethe 2cnd datepicker.

Any help and pointers are most welcome. Thank you.

```
    $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var depDate = new Date(date);
            depDate.setDate(depDate.getDate() + 1);
            $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', depDate);
            
        }
    });
    $("#departureDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly-using-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I needed to get some sleep. Found the solution first thing in the morning.

[src](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-add-1-day-to-selected-day)

```
    $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {       
            var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (newDate) { // Not null
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
            $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate);
        }
    });
    $("#departureDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```